# Angular js Ng-model value not worked in textarea

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here i have the code using ng-model in textarea. i want to get the textarea value and add some static content to that. and then append in ng-model. But it's not working. 
Here i pasted my code:
in html:

```
 <textarea  ng-model="user_text_comment" rows="5" Placeholder="Enter your comments" required="required"></textarea>
<button ng-click="addcardToComments(user_text_comment)"></button>
```

in controller:

```
scope.user_text_comment = "";
$scope.addcardToComments = function(usercomment){
var addComments = "This is an appended text";
$scope.user_text_comment =usercomment.toString()+''+addComments;
console.log($scope.user_text_comment);
});
```

Here console.log print the value corrected. but it's not changed in textarea.

Comment: Did you define a controller in some parent tag?

Comment: can you please provide a fiddle  ?

Comment: Line 1 of controller might be `$scope.user_text_comment = "";` instead of `scope.user_text_comment = "";`

Comment: And yes, please check thoroughly the `ng-controller` and `ng-app` inclusion in your html.

Comment: i added this one in angular material model box. so assign controller for model box.

Answer (score 1):

It is a minor syntax error you have.

```
$scope.addcardToComments = function(usercomment){
  var addComments = "This is an appended text";
  $scope.user_text_comment =usercomment.toString()+''+addComments;
  console.log($scope.user_text_comment);
});
```

The extra "**)**" is not required.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user_text_comment = "";
  $scope.addcardToComments = function(usercomment) {
    var addComments = "This is an appended text";
    $scope.user_text_comment = usercomment.toString() + '' + addComments;
    alert($scope.user_text_comment);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <textarea ng-model="user_text_comment" rows="5" Placeholder="Enter your comments" required="required" style="float:left;"></textarea>
  <button ng-click="addcardToComments(user_text_comment)" style="float:left;">Save</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add $ in line 1 scope.user_text_comment = ""; ($scope.user_text_comment = "";)

and remove toString() of textarea, i think don't need this option.

Thank you..

Comment: If you're not clear whether your answer will work, please post a comment instead.